# Sequential versus simultaneous optimization of multivariate problems

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

Suppose we have the bivariate function $f(x,y)$. I want to solve the following problem:

\begin{equation}
\min\limits_{(x,y)} \; \; f(x,y)
\end{equation}

I want to prove theoretically that simultaneous optimization over $(x,y)$ outperforms the **sequential** optimization approach where the function is optimized over $y$ for a fixed $x$ and then $y$ is fixed at the obtained solution to solve the optimization over $x$ this time and this procedure goes iteratively until the it converges to some solution $(x_{seq}^*, y_{seq}^*)$. Suppose $(x_{sim}^*,y_{sim}^*)$ is the solution obtained from **simultaneous** optimization. I need to show that:

\begin{equation}
f(x_{seq}^*, y_{seq}^*) \; \ge \;  f(x_{sim}^*,y_{sim}^*)
\end{equation}

that is, the optimum achieved by sequential approach is always suboptimal compared with the solution obtained from simultaneous approach.

I appreciate any insights on this. The general problem that I have is non-convex, however I am also interested in the proofs for biconvex case where $f$ is convex in $x$ for each $y$ and convex in $y$ for each $x$.

Comment: By definition $f(x_{seq}^*, y_{seq}^*) \lt  f(x^*,y^*)$ is impossible when $(x^*,y^*) = \arg\min\limits_{(x,y)} f(x,y)$.

Comment: It vastly depends on the methods of optimization you are using, both in the simultaneous case and in the alternating one.

Comment: @joriki I do not understand why this is impossible; can you please elucidate your point? thanks.

Comment: Because $(x^*,y^*) = \arg\min\limits_{(x,y)} f(x,y)$ by definition means that $(x^*,y^*)$ is the point at which $f(x,y)$ takes on its minimum value, so no other value can be lower.

Comment: It is really not clear what you want to show.

Comment: @joriki thanks for the pointer; I edited the problem statement accordingly.

Comment: The problem statement is a bit clearer now, but it's still not quite clear what you're asking. If "simultaneous optimisation" refers to an algorithm that may end up in a local minimum, nothing can be said in this generality and you'll need to specify the algorithm (and perhaps also the function). If, on the other hand, it refers to determining the global minimum, then the inequality that you want show holds by definition of the global minimum.